# Stream videos from amazon to iOS devices

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I store my videos in Amazon S3 bucket and stream them to my website using Cloudfront.
Everything works fine but now I also have an iPad app for my website and I want to stream the same videos to my iPad app.

The only documentation I could found is:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingAdobeFMS4.5.html

It's great explanation how to do live streams on different devices. I also know that CloudFront uses FMS 3.5 and I've set up CloudFormation Stack for FMS 4.5 but I don't know how to connect it to my bucket, create secured urls and stream videos to iOS devices.

Please help and provide me with any documentation that explains how to stream VOD from amazon to iOS devices with secured urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting online with amazon web services support, I was guided to finish my task following way.

1. Launch EC2 instance, from one of [this AMI's](http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/flash-media-server-amazon-machine.html)
2. Connect my S3 to EC2 and configure Adobe FMS 4.5 to pull content from S3. [(How To)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/amazonec2/WS6fc2df2b6d2ce2431afba23c12c3967d3ca-7ff1.2.html#WS0432746db30523c21e63e3d12c9b337c0c-8000.2)
3. Use the EC2 instance as a source for a CloudFront download distribution.

Comment: The reason why I had to do it is that, amazon don't have pre-built solution for it.

Comment: Can I use download distribution? Isn't it streaming one?

Comment: Yes you can use cloudfront download distribution, that was my final choice.

Answer (score 3):

That's really 3 questions:

1. How do I connect CloudFormation to S3? Create a [cloud template that specifies your S3 bucket.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html) Like this:

   {
       "Resources" : {
           "HelloBucket" : {
               "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket"
           }
       }
   }
2. How do I create secure CloudFormation links? Use the [CloudFormation IAM integration.](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/09/powerful-new-features-for-aws-cloudformation.html)
3. How do I stream video on iOS?

You need to use the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) classes.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<#Live stream URL#>"];
// You may find a test stream at http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 

self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

You might need an Apple developer login to follow the link.

Comment: did that help? are you still stuck?

Comment: Unfortunately not, amazon support guided me other way